# How to install graph-tool using pip?

Tags: python, graph-tool

I am trying to use [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/quickstart.html#creating-and-manipulating-graphs), but am unable to find it in pip or [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/graph-tool/)

How can I get it when not using conda?

Please notice I am NOT refering to [graph-tools](https://pypi.org/project/graph-tools/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this is a binary package, it can't be installed with `pip` only. The package maintainers have [explained the issue here](https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/-/wikis/installation-instructions#native-installation), along with various methods to install.

(Using `conda` is one way but there are many other ways to install depending on your OS and how you want to do it.)

Answer (score -6):

One can install graph-tool using pip with the following command-

```
pip install --user graphtools
```

If this is not working than another way to install it is from github using the following command-

```
pip install --user git+git://github.com/KrishnaswamyLab/graphtools.git
```

Here is a [detailed article](https://pypi.org/project/graphtools/#:%7E:text=graphtools%20is%20available%20on%20pip.%20Install%20by%20running,%28most%20easily%20obtained%20via%20the%20Miniconda%20Python%20distribution%29%3A) on the same. Hope this helps!

Comment: I am refering to graph-tool, not graph-tools

Comment: In that case you can download graph tool from [here](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/). It has installation instructions other than conda as well.

Answer (score -6):

Write in your terminal  `pip3 install graph-tools`
I guess you, it will help you a lot.

Comment: I am refering to graph-tool, not graph-tools